# Linemarkers in dimple.js using rCharts

Tags: r, rcharts, dimple.js

I have been experimenting a bit with `dimple.js` using `rCharts` - it's very handy to be able to produce these charts directly from R. What I haven't figured is how to add line markers and/or possibly change the line weight for a simple line chart.

Trivial example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10)+1:10)
d1 <- dPlot(data=df, x='x', y='y', type='line')
d1
```

This is ok, but I want to be able to point users to the tooltips, using line markers - otherwise they have to kind of fumble around for them. It also gives the user a better idea of how many data points there are. Changing the line weight would be just to make it look a bit nicer.

I can see how to do this on the [dimple API](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.series#lineMarkers): I can save the chart using `d1$save('linechart.html', cdn = TRUE)`, then go into the html file and add:

```
s.lineMarkers = true; // s being the series object
s.lineWeight = 3;
```

which works, but is not idea. I have also tried:

```
d1$setTemplate( 
    afterScript = "<script>myChart.series[0].lineMarkers=true;</script>"
)
```

Which *almost* works - but it doesn't render very well. The outlines of the markers don't show and they kind of block out the tooltip.

Ideally, I would be able to access the series object directly in rCharts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are working on addressing and simplying things like this in future versions or `rCharts`.  For now, even though inconvenient, you could do something like this to accomplish your objective, and yes this is far from ideal.  Here it is in a [live example](http://rcharts.io/viewer/live/index.html#?n=eb7b6760524cf7675615).

```
library(rCharts)

df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10)+1:10)
d1 <- dPlot(
  data=df
  , x='x'
  , y='y'
  , type='line'
  , lineWeight=3
)
d1$yAxis( outputFormat = ".2f" )  #show 2 decimal for y points
d1$setTemplate(afterScript = "
<script>
myChart.series[0].lineMarkers = true;
myChart.draw()
myChart.svg.selectAll('circle.markers')
  .style('opacity',1)
myChart.svg.selectAll('circle.markerBacks')
  .style('pointer-events','none')
</script>
"
)
d1
```

If you are willing to try the new experimental dimple branch, you can do

```
#devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/rCharts@dimple_v2.0.0")

library(rCharts)

df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10)+1:10)
d1 <- dPlot(
  data=df
  , x='x'
  , y='y'
  , type='line'
  , lineWeight=3
  , lineMarkers=TRUE
)
d1
```

Comment: 12 Jan. 2015: the first method doesn't work here, but the second one does. This doesn't work for nPlot, I notice.